# If $2\log_3(x-2y)=\log_3x+\log_3y$, find $\frac xy$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

> If $2\log_3(x-2y)=\log_3x+\log_3y$, find $\frac xy$.

My try:

> $$2\log_3(x-2y)=\log_3x+\log_3y$$Combining the terms on the RHS and bringing them over to the LHS $$2\log_3(x-2y)-\log_3xy=0$$ Bring everything into a single $\log$ $$\log_3\frac{(x-2y)^2}{xy}=0$$ Converting this into a solvable quadratic $$x^2-5xy+4y^2=0$$ Factoring, I get $$(x-4)(x-y)=0$$ so $$x=y\;\text{or}\;x=4y$$ Therefore my final answer is $$\frac xy=1\;\text{or}\;\frac xy=4$$

Is my solution correct?

Comment: It is fine to me !

Comment: There's a typo in the factoring

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The final answer is **not** correct.

We have $\log_3(x-2y),\log_3 x$ and $\log_3 y$.

So, we have to have
$$x-2y\gt 0\quad\text{and}\quad x\gt 0\quad\text{and}\quad y\gt 0$$
from which we have to have $$\frac xy\gt 2$$

Hence, from what you've done, the answer is $$\color{red}{\frac xy=4}$$

Answer (score 1):

$$2\log_3(x-2y)=\log_3x+\log_3y$$
$$\log_3(x-2y)^2=\log_3xy$$
$$(x-2y)^2=xy$$
$$x^2-4xy+4y^2-xy=0$$
$$x^2-5xy+4y^2=0$$
$$\frac{x^2}{y^2}-5\frac{x}{y}+4=0$$
$x/y=t$
$$t^2-5t+4=0$$
$$t_{1,2}=\frac{5\pm 3}{2}$$
$$x/y=4,x/y=1$$